# Extract entries from table where specific datetime criteria are satisfied SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `DATATABLE` that contains a timeseries that looks something like this:

```
2018-01-11 09:00:00.000
2018-01-11 09:00:00.000
2018-01-11 09:45:00.000
2018-01-11 09:45:00.000
2018-01-11 10:00:00.000
2018-01-11 10:00:00.000
2018-01-11 10:15:00.000
2018-01-11 10:15:00.000
```

So if I want to extract the timeseries, I would query:

```
SELECT * FROM DATATABLE
```

Now what I want, is to be able to extract part of the timeseries that satisfies specific criteria, which changes each time. The criteria are stored as ranges of values, and so far I have created a procedure that extracts those criteria. One sample criterion would be that the time part of the timeseries should have a value that is contained int he following:

```
00:00:00
00:30:00
01:00:00
01:30:00
02:00:00
02:30:00
03:00:00
03:30:00
04:00:00
04:30:00
05:00:00
05:30:00
06:00:00
06:30:00
07:00:00
07:30:00
08:00:00
08:30:00
09:00:00
09:30:00
10:00:00
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
12:30:00
```

In other words, the values `2018-01-11 09:45:00.000` and `2018-01-11 10:15:00.000` should not be part of my final result. The final result would therefore look like:

```
2018-01-11 09:00:00.000
2018-01-11 09:00:00.000
2018-01-11 10:00:00.000
2018-01-11 10:00:00.000
```

The criterion that I want to set, in English would be:

''Select all the values from my timeseries that have a time part that is (exactly) contained in the series of times I provide you.''

What I wrote so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM DATATABLE
WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE,[DATATABLE].[ISSUETIMES])=(SELECT IssueTimes FROM @IssueTimes)
```

where `@IssueTimes` is a temporary table variable where I store the range of values I want to use as criteria and `[DATATABLE].[ISSUETIMES]` is the column that contains the timeseries that I want to filter.

The error I get is the following:

```
Operand type clash: time is incompatible with int
```

So i get that this probably means that am trying to compare times with int, but i do not know how to proceed as I am kind of new to SQL.

I hope my formulation was good enough to be understandable :)

Comment: You should not use datediff that returns you int, but simply cast your datetime as TIME, and work with it

Comment: I also tried this: `SELECT * FROM DATATABLE WHERE CAST(DATATABLE.ISSUETIMES AS TIME(0)) = (SELECT IssueTimes FROM @IssueTimes)` and i get the following error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what I suggested in comment:

```
declare @dt table (dt datetime);
insert into @dt values
('2018-01-11 09:00:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 09:00:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 09:45:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 09:45:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 10:00:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 10:00:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 10:15:00.000'),
('2018-01-11 10:15:00.000');

declare @tm table (tm time);

insert into @tm values
('00:00:00'),
('00:30:00'),
('01:00:00'),
('01:30:00'),
('02:00:00'),
('02:30:00'),
('03:00:00'),
('03:30:00'),
('04:00:00'),
('04:30:00'),
('05:00:00'),
('05:30:00'),
('06:00:00'),
('06:30:00'),
('07:00:00'),
('07:30:00'),
('08:00:00'),
('08:30:00'),
('09:00:00'),
('09:30:00'),
('10:00:00'),
('10:30:00'),
('11:00:00'),
('11:30:00'),
('12:00:00'),
('12:30:00');

select *
from @dt
where cast(dt as time) in (select tm from @tm);
```

Alternatively, use `exists`:

```
select *
from @dt t
where exists (select * 
              from @tm t1
              where t1.tm = cast(t.dt as time));
```

Comment: Tried it and it works and I just up voted your answer. Thanks :)